# Find the Conditional Probability

Tags: probability-distributions

Let the continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the joint probability density function given by $f(x)$ = $kx$ for $0<x<2$, $0<y<1$, $x<2y$. Find $k$.

I found the joint probability and equated it to one to $k=3/2$. Could that be the right answer? Where $x$ is integrated from $2y$ to $2$ and $y$ from $0$ to $1$.

What is the conditional probability density function $f(x|y)$?

I defined $f(x|y)$ = $f(x,y)$/$f(y)$. But don't know how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\checkmark$ Looks all right so far.  (Although $x$ needs to be integrated from $0$ to $2y$.)

You'll next need to use: $$\begin{align}
 f(y)
 & = \int_0^{2y} f(x,y)\operatorname d x  \cdot\operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(y)
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac 3 2 \int_0^{2y} x \operatorname d x\cdot\operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(y) 
\\[3ex]
 & = 3 y^2\cdot\operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(y)
\\[2ex]\hline
f(x\mid y) & = \frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}
\\[1ex]
& = \frac{x}{2 y^2}\cdot\operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(y)\cdot\operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,2y)}(x)
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Thanks Graham. Does it suffice to say that $f(x)$ = 3/2x?

Comment: I tried finding $P(x<1.5|y=0.5)$ but got 2.25. That doesnt appear right since the probability cannot be greater than one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @J.R. Did you consider the *support* for the conditional density function? $\\ \mathsf P(x<1.5\mid y=0.5) = \int_0^1 \frac{ x }{2(0.5)^2} \operatorname d x = 1$; because $y=0.5 \land x\in(0,2y)\Rightarrow x\in(0,1)$

Comment: I forgot to change the limits of integration. But your input helped.

Comment: I want help with this question.

Find the probability density function $U=X-Y$. Use figures to help you find $f(u)$.

I approached this problem using transformation and had $0<u<2$. I need to find the distribution function for $0<u<1$ and $1<u<2$. But the limits of integral is my headache. Is there a better way in deriving the limits.